# PHP error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_grpc'

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, composer-php, grpc

I have tried so many things. Literally taken me a week of trial and error. I managed to get the realtime firebase DB working but not the firestore as I can't call the command

```
  composer require google/cloud-firestore
```

I have tried fresh installs 3 times for PHP and the other software. This really is not working. Why do I have to use this composer thing and them not just put a zip with all the relevant files inside?

With extension=php.dll in ini:
[image: With extension=php.dll in ini]

and changing to aboslute path surrounding extension, with and without .dll I have tried.

[image]

I've tried threadsafe and non threadsafe versions, and I also don't know what "1% is not a valid command" is. Also have tried x64 and x86 versions. The previous two images are x86 (which I assume to be 64 as my os is)

Here is an example of a x64 (I assume is 32bit) error. Procedure points cannot be found and it gives an error about entry points.

[image]

Comment: Yes. I've tried all of those files

Comment: Please never share text output in images. Text can be shared best in text form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what I did but I fixed it. To those reading this question just make sure in every place there is a php.ini they are the same directory!